# Mixing types in function declaration multifunction programs

Tags: c

I'm having trouble getting my program to actually compute any values after it computes area.

It computes that just fine and I was proud of myself for getting it bug free.

But now it is just spitting out blank lines and asking for more after my scanf statement asking for double. Why?

I coded a printf to get back my scanf value just to check to see if the compiler was getting it. It isn't. I don't get it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{ int length;
  int width;
  int area;
  double costPersqft;

//Statements
  printf("Enter length in feet: ");
  scanf("%d", &length);
  printf("Enter width in feet: ");
  scanf("%d", &width);

  int get_Area (int x, int y)
  {
  return(x*y);
  }//Area

  area = get_Area (length, width);

  printf("Length: %d\n", length);
  printf("Width: %d\n", width);    
  printf("Area: %d\n", area);

  printf("Enter cost per square foot: ");
  scanf("%f", &costPersqft);
  printf("%.2f", costPersqft);

  return 0;
}//Main
```

Comment: Perhaps try using `%lf` rather than `%f`?

Comment: @ahe No, it should be `%lf`

Comment: @MikeCAT yup, whoops! Mistyped.

Comment: Passing pointer to object having wrong type to `scanf()` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: "It computes that just fine and I was proud of myself for getting it bug free." Be careful! Compiling DO NOT mean that there are no bug.

Comment: Note that nesting of function in C is GCC extension and is not in the standard. You won't need it in this case.

Comment: changed to lf no go.

Comment: MikeCAT I don't think I understand. Nesting of function in C is GCC extension?

Comment: "asking for more after my scanf statement". What does that mean exactly? Please show the exact test run log - paste it as text into the question. But for starters `scanf("%f", &costPersqft);`. The `%f` directive expects a pointer to float but you are giving it a pointer to double. Change the type of `costPersqft` to be `float` (or change `%f` to `%lf` to handle double).

Comment: That worked. Now for the other functions!!!

Comment: For the record EVERYTHING in the thing worked, I guess that nestedness isn't an issue for standard in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, your main problem is the use of a wrong format specifier in your `scanf`. The correct format specifier for a `double` is `%lf`, not `%f`. Using the wrong format specifier invokes Undefined Behavior.

So change

```
scanf("%f", &costPersqft);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf", &costPersqft);
```

---

You should also check the return value of all your `scanf`s. In your case, all of them will return 1 if successful.

---

The compiler would've shown you a warning if you've enabled them. Use `-Wall -Wextra` to enable warnings. Pay heed to the warnings and don't ignore them.

---

Also, [Nested functions are a GCC extenion](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) as [said by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787515/mixing-types-in-function-declaration-multifunction-programs/35788711#comment59246125_35787515) [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4062354/mikecat) in the comments under your question. It is not standard C. So I suggest moving

```
int get_Area (int x, int y)
{
  return(x * y);
}
```

just before the definition of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

It's jumbled at the bottom but those results are directly from my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define tax 0.085
#define fixedRate .35

int main (void)
{ int length;
  int width;
  int area;
  double costPersqft;
  double carpet_charge;
  double labor;
  double installed_price;
  double actual_discount;
  double subtotal;
  double discount;
  double tax_amount;
  double total;

//Statements
  printf("Enter length in feet: ");
  scanf("%d", &length);
  printf("Enter width in feet: ");
  scanf("%d", &width);
  printf("Enter customer discount (xx.xx): ");
  scanf("%lf", &discount);
  printf("Enter cost per square foot(xxx.xx): ");
  scanf("%lf", &costPersqft);

  int get_Area (int x, int y)
  {
  return(x*y);
  }//Area
area = get_Area (length, width);
  printf("               MEASUREMENT        \n");
  printf("Length:                     %d ft \n", length);
  printf("Width:                      %d ft \n", width);
  printf("Area:                       %d square ft \n",
area);

  double get_Cacharge (int p, double q)
  { double product;
  product = p * q;
  return product;
  }//Area times costpersqft is charges for carpet

  carpet_charge = get_Cacharge (area, costPersqft);
  printf("                CHARGES              \n");
  printf("DESCRIPTION   COST/SQ.FT.      CHARGE\n");
  printf("-----------   -----------   -----------\n");
  printf("Carpet Cost      %5.2lf        $%8.2lf\n", costPersqft, carpet_charge);

  double get_Laborcost (int r)
  { double labor = 0.35;
    double product;
    product = r * labor;
    return product;
  }//labor cost

  labor = get_Laborcost (area);

  printf("Labor            %5.2lf         %8.2lf\n", fixedRate, labor);
  printf("                            -----------\n");
  installed_price = labor + carpet_charge;
printf("Installed Price               $%8.2lf\n", installed_price);

  double get_Discount (double c, double d)
  { double temp;
    temp = c * d;
    return temp;
  }

  actual_discount = get_Discount (installed_price, discount);

  printf("Discount         %5.2lf         %8.2lf\n", discount, actual_discount);
  printf("                            -----------\n");
  subtotal = installed_price - actual_discount;

  printf("Subtotal                      $%8.2lf\n", subtotal);

  tax_amount = tax * subtotal;
printf("Tax                            %8.2lf\n", tax_amount);

  total = subtotal + tax_amount;

 printf("Total                         $%8.2lf\n", total);

  return 0;
}//Main
```

Enter length in feet: 14
Enter width in feet: 11
Enter customer discount (xx.xx): 00.10
Enter cost per square foot(xxx.xx): 022.25
               MEASUREMENT
Length:                     14 ft 
Width:                      11 ft 
Area:                       154 square ft 
                CHARGES
DESCRIPTION   COST/SQ.FT.      CHARGE
-----------   -----------   -----------
Carpet Cost      22.25        $ 3426.50
Labor             0.35            53.90
                            -----------
Installed Price               $ 3480.40
Discount          0.10           348.04
                            -----------
Subtotal                      $ 3132.36
Tax                              266.25
Total                         $ 3398.61